# Convert each component of a list to different data frames in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have an excel file that has multiple sheets in fact 12 sheets corresponding to 12 months in a year. For each sheet, I have data for admissions for each hospital in UK. I have managed to read these sheets in R by using the following code/function:

```
library("readxl")
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename) {
sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
x <-    lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
names(x) <- sheets
x
}
mysheet <- read_excel_allsheets("Daycase0809.xlsx")
```

After executing the function, I basically get a list called mysheet where each component of the list (the length varies from year to year) corresponds to the admission data for each month of the year.

What I basically want (and so far I am struggling) is to convert each component of the list to a single data frame object for all of the 12 components. So basically there would be 12 data frames corresponding to 12 months.

I have managed to do this but it is inefficient which involves writing 12 lines of R statement as demonstrated below:

```
Daycase_1_0809 <- as.data.frame(mysheet[[1]])
```

I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing it. I imagine it has do with strings and loop but I am relatively new in R.

Afterwards, I use the data for descriptive and further analysis and merge the data with other data.

Your help would be much appreciated since it allow me to economize on time, help me to learn for future use and also will allow my R script to look neat.

Comment: How do you want to name the objects? Because if you create a vector of names like `df_names <- paste("df", 1:12, sep = "_")`, you could then maybe just use `for` and `assign`. `for (i in 1:12) assign(df_names[i], mysheet[[i]])`.

Comment: I would like to name as df1, df2 and so on but df_1, df_2 etc. is also fine.Thanks, the statement works very nicely!

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
lapply(mysheet, as.data.frame)
```

If the items are not already `data.frame`s.

---

To put the `data.frame`s into your global environment, you can use `list2env`, but you should first name your list items.

So, the approach would be something like:

```
list2env(
    setNames(
        lapply(mysheet, as.data.frame), c("A", "Vector", "of", "names")),
    .GlobalEnv)
```